# Where can I write my AsyncTasks

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm creating an application which makes extensive use of `AsyncTask` to retrieve data from a database. My problem is I've got nearly 12 different `AsyncTasks` and it's making my code dirtier and dirtier, plus the fact that some tasks are shared among different activities.

Some of the `AsyncTask` I've already written have their own java class file, but it's not an always ideal since some requests need to access application's resources (making the use of `Resources.getSystem().getString(stringId)` impossible, or requiring to pass instances I need to modify as parameters as reference)

Is there any recommended way to write `AsyncTask` classes ?

Comment: What's wrong with passing in the necessary external objects as parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to say without knowing the exact circumstances but if you have some that do similar tasks then you can create them in their own file and create constructors that take the parameters you need.

You can set them up to accept a `Context`, `Activity` object, etc...then make them reusable. If you have some that are only necessary for a certain `Activity` then I would make it an inner class but if it is used by multiple `Activities` then I would make it a separate class and use constructor(s) to take the needed parameters.

I have many `AsyncTasks` in my applications and it just depends on how you need them. As I said, you can pass a `Context` to the constructor when you need it for objects that require a `Context`. Just pass it like

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(this);  // for passing Context or any other params the constructor takes
task.execute();
```

And in the task

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<...>  // add AsyncTask params
{
     Context context;
     public MyTask(Context c)
     {
         context = c;
     }
     // methods
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about creating constructors that take `Context` as a parameter ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're welcome. You can also pass in `Views` or any other object you need.